# d3, parsing a csv file with commas in data (using d3.csv.parseRows())

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have a simple CSV file (text.csv) with the a structure like this:

```
a, line number1
b, line number2
c, "line number3, including comma"
d, line number4
```

I'm trying to parse the file with d3 using d3.csv.parseRows and I'm expecting it to create for me a simple array structure as follows:

```
d3.csv.parseRows(csvTextFile)
```

expecting it to give:

```
[
  [a, "line number1"],
  [b, "line number2"],
  [c, "line number3, including comma"],
  [d, "line number4]
]
```

Instead, it seems to be interpreting the comma on the third line as a delimiter, even though it's included in quotations marks, so what I actually get is:

```
[
  [a, "line number1"],
  [b, "line number2"],
  [c, "line number3", "including comma"],  <<--- not expecting this
  [d, "line number4]
]
```

Can someone help me — were am I going wrong or is there another approach I should be taking?

Many thanks

Comment: Works for me with `d3.csv` -- http://plnkr.co/edit/wQ86y3MJkvKVX3tBRcFO?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Lars, I appreciate you taking the time and effort to answer. I'm not sure that's the same thing. I'm using parseRows and assigning the output to a variable: thus: var testCSVParsed = d3.csv.parseRows("test.csv"). I tried to set something up in Plunker but ran into some issues — I'll try again and post back if successful.

Comment: `.parseRows()` takes a string which is the contents of the file, not the file name, so I don't see how you could have gotten the result above with this code.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do, Lars. Unfortunately, it's not working as expected in Plunker but the code is more or less that: http://plnkr.co/edit/oLaOh3Tnsp3GY9shaCzR?p=preview (when I do this locally, the console log will show something like this: [
Array[2]
, 
Array[2]
, 
Array[3]
, 
Array[2]
]

Comment: In my code, I don't use the file name but a variable which points to the CSV file contents, which is loaded first through an Ajax call.

Comment: Please post the content of the variable with the CSV file content or the full code so we can help you to indentify the problem.

Comment: So something like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/MVSPALZvjSmLivJWL1Su?p=preview)? Works fine for me as well.

Comment: Yes, precisely. And it does work fine, I see. So, I think the problem is linked to the fact that I'm not using d3.text to load the file but jQuery get (I swapped after I ran into difficulties with https for some reason on the with d3.text() I think — supporting https is no longer an issue so I'll go back). Thanks for all your help — much appreciated.

Comment: In fact, after testing, that wasn't the problem at all. It's actually visible in my posted code but I didn't realise it was a problem. Basically, if you look at my .csv file there are spaces after the commas, which I hadn't spotted. Once I remove them, the problem seems to be resolved. But again, thanks Lars, because I wouldn't have spotted that for a long time unless you had posted a solution.